# Cauchy's Principal Value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(x)/(a-x)dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus, cauchy-principal-value

How do I go about finding the principal value of this integral?
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{a-x}dx$$
[Another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245429/cauchy-principle-value-of-int-infty-infty-sinx-x-adx) suggested that shifting the integrand by making the change $x \rightarrow x+a$ is one way to simplify to two easier integrals. Can someone help me solve this without changing the integrand like that with a more direct approach (a summary of it will suffice)?

Thank you

Comment: Is $a$ real, in the upper half plane, or in the lower half plane? In any case, this is a standard contour integral exercise

Comment: Yes, $a$ is real valued.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245429/cauchy-principle-value-of-int-infty-infty-sinx-x-adx with sign reversed

Comment: Well, yes, it does find the principal value of the integral, but I was wondering how I would solve it without making the change $x \rightarrow x+a$, as suggested by that post. How would a more direct approach look like?

Comment: The alternative is to use that $$pv(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{a-x}dx)=\frac12(\int_{C_+}\frac{\sin(z)}{a-z}dz+\int_{C_-}\frac{\sin(z)}{a-z}dz)$$ where $C_+,C_-$ are two contours following the real line but passing slightly above and below $a$.  Then $\int_{C_\pm} \frac{e^{\pm iz}}{z-a}$ is found with the residue theorem.